# Angular 2 data binding in nested *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have two lists: `devices` and `groups`
Devices have a `group_id` property

In a template I have the following:

```
<li *ngFor="let group of groups">
   <h3>{{group.title}}</h3>
      <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let item of devices | matchesGroup:group.id">/// </li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

The pipe `matchesGroup` simply filters devices by `group_id`.

```
transform(items: Array<Device>, group: number): Array<any> {
        return items.filter(item => item.group_id === group);
    }
```

So I have a list of device groups. In each group I have a list of deveices.

When I change the `group_id` property of any device the lists are not updating.
**The device with new `group_id` stays in previous group.**
Why? How can I make the nested *ngFor track changes of device?

As I see what should happen.. Nested ngFor should detect change of `device` property and refresh all device lists. The `matchGroup` pipe would filter each list and leave only those devices which match corresponding group.

Comment: It will a lot more easier if you send normalize data to view (html)

Comment: using impure pipe or immutable object/array https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes

Comment: @tiep-phan, thank you. That is what I was missing.